# Python threading Flask - do I need to close my thread using x.join()?

Tags: python, flask, python-multithreading

I have some code in Python Flask which does the following:

1. get user input
2. calculates (0.3s)
3. writes to DB (3s)
4. return view to user

Currently the user has to wait 3.3s for the view to return to them, so I'd like to return the view to the user while I write to the DB. My plan is to use threading for this, but I can never run x.join(). This is my code:

```py
import threading

def something_slow(my_variable):
    print(f"Thread is starting and will execute on {my_variable}")
    time.sleep(3)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Starting")
    x = threading.Thread(target=something_slow, args=('my variable, probably a SQL query',))
    x.start()
    print("this code will execute while the slow thing is happening")
    # code that will execute while something slow is happening:
    return render_template('results.html')

    x.join() # this wil NEVER execute!!!
    print('something slow is done')
```

From what I can tell on the [internet](https://superfastpython.com/thread-close/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20close%20a%20thread,the%20run()%20function%20directly.), the thread will close when I call `return` from inside the thread. Is it true that as long as I call `return` inside the thread, I don't need to run `x.join()` to close?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, no. A thread will only exit with a `return` or an exception that causes the thread function to terminate. This exit leaves some thread information in memory for the `.join` to clean up. The `.join` does not terminate the thread - but it, along with deleting the `Thread` object you created, will clean up that memory.

Python keeps a list of created threads and will do a `.join` on each of them when your program exits. If you create a thread with `daemon=True`, it is not added to the list and there is no final join. Any daemon threads still running are killed when the process exits.

But generally, the idea is that you can create a thread and not worry about joining or even worry whether the thread has completed when `__main__` exits. If the thread's work is not done, python will do that wait for you. That's what's happening in your case. Unless you really want that print when the thread completes, skip the join and the print and let python do the wait.

If your code really needs to know when a thread is complete then you do the join yourself. If it's a long-running program that creates a bunch of threads, then you may need to do your own joins to make sure the dead thread resources are freed.

Comment: Thanks so much @tdelaney! So here's my use-case: it's a flask app that gets user input, does some calculations and writes to a DB. This means that for each user query, I will generate a thread (which can be in the hundreds or even thousands). I'm not sure that __main__ will ever exit, because the app is started only once. So will I have memory leakage issues in this case?

Comment: Yes. You'll need some mechanism to do the join. The best way depends on the overall design of your program. One option is to use a long lived thread pool